# How to compare the dimensions of two blocks?

Tags: inequality

Consider I have the dimensions of two boxes (length x width x height), what would 
be the easiest way to compare them, allowing N% error?

For example, 20x30x40 would be the same box as 40x30x20, so directly comparing length, width and height won't work.

How can I best do that?

Comment: $N\%$ error in what?

Comment: In each dimension. So, 40x30x20 would be considered equal to 41x29x21 if N=10.

Comment: Rank the three dimensions then compare each ordered pair with your criterion